# what is the difference between s3-website-some-region and s3-website.some-region?

Tags: amazon-s3

my s3 static website bucket has the full url as this

http://frontend-erjan-result.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

does it matter if the example i m following has dot and not 'dash' before the region name?

"s3-website-region" vs "s3-website.region"

http://frontend-erjan-result.s3-website.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

is it crucial or does not matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official s3-website endpoints are [listed in the S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html) (scroll down to “Amazon S3 website endpoints”). There is an apparent inconsistency, some have a hyphen, some have a dot.

To be honest, I didn’t know this myself. My guess is that it has historic reasons; I could imagine that they started with the hyphenated version for the early regions (us-east-1, eu-west-1) and then switched to the dot notation, possibly allowing  easier DNS zone management based on AWS Regions. And I guess that at the same time, a fallback was created so that the dot notation is also supported for the hyphenated endpoints in order to be consistent, especially for the purposes of automation. Again, this is just an assumption.

Comment: i suspect it does not matter if its dot or dash, thx anyways.